# Pandas: Changing the value of a column based on a string existing in the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a list of movies and I want to change the value of the column to 0 if the string "Action" exists in the column or 1 if the string "Drama" exists. If both exists then change the value to 0 since the genre "Action" is more important.

For example lets say I have the table below:

| Genres |
| --- |
| Action Comedy Adventure |
| Drama Crime Horror |
| Action Drama Adventure |

I want it to change to this:

| Genres |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 0 |

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What is output if no match `Drama` or `Action` ?

Comment: If neither than it changes to NaN

Comment: Added to answer `default=np.nan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), if not match both condition is set `NaN` by parameter `default`:

```
#if test substrings
m1 = df['Genres'].str.contains('Drama')
m2 = df['Genres'].str.contains('Action')

#if test lists
m1 = ['Drama' in x for x in df['Genres']]
m2 = ['Action' in x for x in df['Genres']]

df['Genres'] = np.select([(m1 & m2) | m2, m1], [0, 1], default=np.nan)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) your keywords, and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) from a mapping dictionary, in case of multiple matches let's get the [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.min.html) number (you can use another rule if needed):

```
import re

d = {'Action': 0, 'Drama': 1}

pattern = f"({'|'.join(map(re.escape, d))})"
# pattern = '(Drama|Action)'

df['Genres'] = (df['Genres'].str.extractall(pattern)[0]
                 .map(d).groupby(level=0).min()
               )
```

Output:

```
   Genres
0       0
1       1
2       0
```

Output if we add another row with no match:

```
   Genres
0     0.0
1     1.0
2     0.0
3     NaN
```